# How to make a simple toggle button work using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to build a simple  toggle button to change the classes on an element and its text of the containing 'p' element.

On the first click it works just fine, but then it doesn't toggle back.

What do I miss here?

```js
$('.disclaimer').click(function() {
    if ($('#disclaimerText').text = "Disclaimer Declined") {
        $('.disclaimer').addClass("disclaimerAccepted");
        $('#disclaimerText').text("Disclaimer Accepted")
    } else {
        $('.disclaimer').removeClass("disclaimerAccepted");
        $('#disclaimerText').text("Disclaimer Declined")
    }
});
```

```css
.disclaimer {
    font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 0.7vw;
    width: 15%;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: #f96c8a;
    color: #545d7b;
}

.disclaimerAccepted {
    font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 0.7vw;
    width: 15%;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: #30e83a;
    color: #545d7b;
}

#disclaimerText {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    font-size: 2vw;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="disclaimer">
    <p id="disclaimerText">Disclaimer Declined</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [**`.toggleClass()`**](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/):

> Add or remove one or more classes from each element in the set of matched elements, depending on either the class's presence or the value of the state argument.

**Please Note:** `text` is a jQuery method, to get the text you have to use `.text()` and also instead of assignment operator (`=`), you have to use comparison operator (`==` or `===`) to compare the text:

```js
$('.disclaimer').click(function() {
  $('.disclaimer').toggleClass("disclaimerAccepted");
  if ($('#disclaimerText').text() == "Disclaimer Declined") {        
    $('#disclaimerText').text("Disclaimer Accepted")
  } else {
    $('#disclaimerText').text("Disclaimer Declined")
  }
});
```

```css
.disclaimer {
    font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 0.7vw;
    width: 15%;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: #f96c8a;
    color: #545d7b;
}

.disclaimerAccepted {
    font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 0.7vw;
    width: 15%;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: #30e83a;
    color: #545d7b;
}

#disclaimerText {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    font-size: 2vw;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="disclaimer">
  <p id="disclaimerText">Disclaimer Declined</p>
</div>
```

Comment: And how to additionally change the text on toggle/click? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I mean I want the text to change to "Disclaimer Accepted" or "Disclaimer Declined" depending on the toggle status (so changing text back and forth on each click of the div)

Answer (score 2):

You wrong at `text()` instead of text, and missing `==` instead of `=` is assign operator

Change from

```
if ($('#disclaimerText').text = "Disclaimer Declined") {
```

to

```
 if ($('#disclaimerText').text() == "Disclaimer Declined") {
```

```js
$('.disclaimer').click(function() {
    if ($('#disclaimerText').text() == "Disclaimer Declined") {
    
        $('.disclaimer').addClass("disclaimerAccepted");
        $('#disclaimerText').text("Disclaimer Accepted")
    } 
    else {
       
        $('.disclaimer').removeClass("disclaimerAccepted");
        $('#disclaimerText').text("Disclaimer Declined")
    }
});
```

```css
.disclaimer {
    font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 0.7vw;
    width: 15%;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: #f96c8a;
    color: #545d7b;
}

.disclaimerAccepted {
    font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 0.7vw;
    width: 15%;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: #30e83a;
    color: #545d7b;
}

#disclaimerText {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    font-size: 2vw;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="disclaimer">
    <p id="disclaimerText">Disclaimer Declined</p>
</div>
```